# Best way to load images in RecyclerView while scrolling with the help of RxJava

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview, rx-java

I have a RecylerView with a ViewHolder. And I need to load and display image into that ViewHolder. Images are loading from my helper class. For the first time the are loading with the help of my native library, written on C, then they are saving into cache. And for the second time they are loading into ViewHolder from cache. And now I am wondering how to do this job with the help of RxJava.
At the current moment I see two ways of how to implement this.
1. Create an Observable and Observer for every ViewHolder item in my recycler while it is scrolling. Actually - right now I am using this solution, but I think it is not good from the performance point of view
2. Create only one instance of Observable per my Recycler and every ViewHolder item will subscribe to it? But at the current moment I have no ideas how to do that? I can create one Observable instance, but how to pass it parameters - which number of image i need to load into this current ViewHolder? 
May be you could give me some ideas of the best ways of how to load images into ViewHolder? 
Thanks